# Error handling PHP function

Tags: php

So I want to make a function to display errors instead of saying `echo "error message"`, I want something like `$this->errorDisplay('error message');`

I currently have this, but it's not doing the job.

```
function errorDisplay($msg) {
  $this->errors[] = $msg;

  foreach($this->errors as $error) {
    echo $error;
  }

}

public function checkFields($username,$password) {
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
       //proceed to validation
    } else {
        $this->errorDisplay('All fields are required.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function is doing two things at once: collecting messages, and outputting previously collected ones. Split it up if that's what you actually want to do.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to happen?

Comment: Why are you putting all the errors in an array if you just want to display one error?

Comment: Move it around to where? Please rewrite the question and get very clear about what you expect the result to be when you call this multiple times. Where are all the errors supposed to be displayed?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this.

Comment: You still have not made it clear what you actually want to do

Comment: I want to make a function to display errors instead of saying echo "error message", I want something like $this->errorDisplay('error message');

Comment: This is pretty unclear as to what you're asking. You need to give us the expected output and current output. All you have said so far is that your code isn't doing the job. *What is it doing right now? What is it supposed to be doing?* You have not provided that information.

Comment: @Zsw My guess is he has taken what he wants and dissappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do everything in one method, split the process into 2. One method adds messages to an array, and the other shows all the previously saved up messages.

```
Class xxx
{

    public $errors = array();

    public function addError($msg) {
        $this->errors[] = $msg;
    }

    public function showErrors() {
        foreach($this->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }

    public function initErrors() {
        $this->errors = array();
    }

    public function checkFields($username,$password) {

        $this->initErrors();

        if( empty($username)  ) {
            $this-addError('Username missing');
        }
        if ( empty($password) ) {
            $this-addError('Password missing');
        } 

        if ( count($this->errors) > 0 ) {
            $this->showErrors();
        }
    }
} //end class
```